# How can I prevent circles to get clipped when map is pitched/tilted in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

Adding circles in a Mapbox GL JS map with a satellite style layer works well, however, the circles get increasingly clipped when I apply pitch values to the map, like so:

[image: clipped circles for satellite style layer]

Code [here](http://blockbuilder.org/larsvers/d5017c96cd210e368b1aef4a3354ea93)

Play with the pitch/tilt control in the upper right corner to see the changing circle clipping...

[image: pitch control]

This only seems to happen in the satellite style, but not for non-satellite style layers like for example the 'Outdoor' style:

[image: unclipped circles for outdoor style layer]

Code [here](http://blockbuilder.org/larsvers/6abbe8b99e9005bb6b301d40f1b6e88e)

My main question is how can I prevent this from happening and I of course also wonder what the reason for this is?

Comment: This seems like it might be a legitimate bug in our rendering code. Posted Github issue [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3563)